# Dynamic Backbone Template Variable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
// Template Helper
window.template = function (id) {
return _.template($('#' + id).html());
};

// Template Helper in view.render
this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );

// This Template Call in View
template: template('response-form')

// This My If Else Construction in View Initialize
if (this.model.attributes.status === true) {
  here i want set template id to response-auth
} else {
  here i want set template id to response-form
}
```

I dont have idea, how i can dynamicly change value of template call? Did someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `this.template` whenever you want inside your view. So, you could check the status in your view's `initialize`:

```
initialize: function() {
    if(this.model.get('status'))
        this.template = template('response-auth');
    else
        this.template = template('response-form');
}
```

Or you could make the decision inside `render`:

```
render: function() {
    var tmpl = null;
    if(this.model.get('status'))
        tmpl = template('response-auth');
    else
        tmpl = template('response-form');

    // your current rendering code goes here but uses
    // tmpl instead of this.template
}
```

Which approach you take depends on whether or not you're expecting the status to change.

You could, of course, compile both when building the view:

```
template_auth: template('response-auth'),
template_form: template('response-form'),
initialize: function() {
    // Set this.template to this.template_auth or this.template_form...
},
render: function() {
    // Or pick this.template_auth or this.template_form in here if
    // that makes sense...
}
```

If you're expecting to use both templates then compiling them both would make sense, otherwise I'd leave the decision until it needs to be made (probably in `render`).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined underscore.js:1

Comment: With which version? That usually means that you're trying to `_.template` something that isn't in the DOM yet. The usual `$(document).ready()` approach should work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/47MsV/

Here all my code.
Backbone & Underscore & Jquery Latest

Comment: You forgot to bring in jQuery, Underscore, and Backbone in that. And I don't see where the templates are. Add the templates to http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yzDHT/ and see what happens.

Comment: Something was overwriting the `<div class="ra-response-login-page"></div>` content and that's where your template `<script>`s were. Moving the template `<script>`s outside that `<div>` makes that problem go away: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yzDHT/3/ You're generally better off putting the template `<script>`s inside `<head>` so that you won't accidentally overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

@mu is too short: Isn't any way by which we can pass dynamic data inside

> template('response-auth');

Suppose I got more than 50 template, then I can't put if else statement.

```
$(`#channel-view-${targetPlatformId}`).html(_.template(templates.manage_store_form_template_Ebay)({


$(`#channel-view-${targetPlatformId}`).html(_.template(templates.manage_store_form_template_shopify)({
```

There is one difference in above line, that is channel name, Is there any way I can pass dynamic data inside **_.template()**